# Can I use GIT_CONFIG environment variable to use a config file for all git commands

Tags: bash, git, git-config

I have been trying to use git config file by `export GIT_CONFIG=<file>` in a shell script.
But setting from the file are not being used. My goal is to use settings from file for all subsequent git commands.

If the settings are in global config file they are being used.

From using `GIT_TRACE=1` I see that `GIT_CONFIG` is being unset.

Does `git clone` `unset GIT_CONFIG`?

```
run-command.c:646       trace: run_command: unset GIT_CONFIG GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git clone --no-checkout --separate-git-dir \
```

Git version being used: `2.17.1`

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

You should use `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` instead of `GIT_CONFIG`.

`GIT_CONFIG` is only used in the `git config` command, and the git manual has [this to say about it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-GITCONFIG):

> ###### GIT_CONFIG
>
> If no --file option is provided to git config, use the file given by GIT_CONFIG as if it were provided via --file. **This variable has no effect on other Git commands, and is mostly for historical compatibility**; there is generally no reason to use it instead of the --file option.

[emphasis is mine]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a config file to your git config for all operations, you can add an `include.path` directive.

```bash
# "~" expands to $HOME
git config --global include.path '~/path/to/config'
# "./" = Relative to global git config file, e.g. "./foo" = "~/.config/git/foo"
git config --global include.path './relative/path'
```

Here's the relevant section of `git help config`:

> **Includes**
>
> The `include` and `includeIf` sections allow you to include config directives from
> another source. These sections behave identically to each other with the
> exception that `includeIf` sections may be ignored if their condition does not
> evaluate to true; see "Conditional includes" below.
>
> You can include a config file from another by setting the special `include.path`
> (or `includeIf.*.path`) variable to the name of the file to be included. The
> variable takes a pathname as its value, and is subject to tilde expansion. These
> variables can be given multiple times.
>
> The contents of the included file are inserted immediately, as if they had been
> found at the location of the include directive. If the value of the variable is a
> relative path, the path is considered to be relative to the configuration file in
> which the include directive was found. See below for examples.